# how to fix vertical position of y=0 axis even if data changes (data will be negative)

Tags: highcharts

In column highchart in case of negative value whenever I change values then y=0 axis moves upwards or downwards but i want to fix position of y=0 axis in middle and want to grow column height accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tickPositioner` function to create a mirror image of the axis and always have a zero value in the middle:

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var defaultTicks = this.tickPositions,
            isMorePositive = Math.abs(defaultTicks[0]) <
                defaultTicks[defaultTicks.length - 1],
            tickPositions = [];

        defaultTicks.forEach(function(el) {
            if (isMorePositive ? (el > 0) : (el < 0)) {
                tickPositions.push(el);
                tickPositions.push(-el);
            } else if (el === 0) {
                tickPositions.push(el);
            }
        });

        return tickPositions.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b
        });
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o97Lmdqa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.tickPositioner